# В чём отличие работы GetEnumerator()-ов в C#?

Tags: c#

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

var x1 = new { Items = ((IEnumerable<int>)list).GetEnumerator() };
while (x1.Items.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x1.Items.Current);
}

Console.ReadLine();

var x2 = new { Items = list.GetEnumerator() };
while (x2.Items.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x2.Items.Current);
}
```

Почему первый код выводит 1 2 3
А второй бесконечно спамит 0.

Я понимаю что здесь дело в утиной типизации и методе GetEnumerator(). Но хотелось бы услышать подробное объяснение.

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что вы в анонимный тип засовываете структуру. Более подробно можете почитать к примеру [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23537567/6808809).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ здесь:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var x1 = new { Items = ((IEnumerable<int>)list).GetEnumerator() };
    var x2 = new { Items = list.GetEnumerator() };
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x1.Items, x1.Items));
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x2.Items, x2.Items));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
True
False
```

А всё почему? [А вот почему](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L1145)

```
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerator
{
    // ...
}
```

`List<T>.Enumerator` - структура. А что происходит, когда вы пытаетесь получить структуру из свойста? Правильно, копирование. Точно так же как это происходит при возврате значения из метода.

Даже вот здесь предупреждение

```
// CA2013 Do not pass an argument with value type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Enumerator' to 'ReferenceEquals'.
// Due to value boxing, this call to 'ReferenceEquals' will always return 'false'.
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x2.Items, x2.Items));
```

Апкаст к `IEnumerator` или `IEnumerator<T>` позволяет забоксить структуру лишь однажды при присваивании.

А сделано это так для того чтобы при вызове `.GetEnumerator()` на списке не производилась аллокация в куче. Такой энумератор на стеке отработает быстрее и не будет создавать лишней работы для сборщика мусора.

---

Вот этот код не сгенерирует мусора.

```
List<int>.Enumerator enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

Даже `Dispose` этому энумератору вызывать не нужно. Так как он сидит в стеке, то будет уничтожен вместе с возвратом из метода.

Comment: "А что происходит, когда вы пытаетесь получить структуру из поля? Правильно, копирование." На самом деле в рассматриваемом коде мы не пытаемся получить структуру, а всего лишь получить доступ к её членам. И этот доступ разный в зависимости от того, к полю какого типа идёт обращение: значащего или ссылочного (см. мой ответ). Не могу найти, где это специфицировано или, хотя-бы, описано, или из чего это следует.

Comment: @rotabor доступ к нестатическим членам чего-либо происходит через экземпляр этой сущности. Я не знаю, как полноценно комментировать то что вы написали, потому что не понимаю написанного. Ответ тоже не понимаю, это слишком сложно. Почитайте что-нибудь про боксинг-анбоксинг.

Comment: Ага, разобрался - там происходит неявная упаковка/распаковка.

Comment: Не согласен. В описании анонимного типа (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) нет указаний на то, что тип поля будет какой-то иной, а не тип присваеваемого ему значения. Компилятор явно показывает, что "x2.Items" имеет тип "System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Enumerator", и причин для упаковки и распаковки нет. Поэтому предлагаю вариант -  см. мой ответ.

Comment: @rotabor упаковка и распаковка тут ни при чём, дело именно в копировании структуры когда вы "достаёте" её из свойства.

Comment: @rotabor вы не можете получить доступ к членам структуры не получив сначала эту структуру. А она копируется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да ну? Изменил свой ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Давайте поизучаем https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugHQDCA9hBAKYDGwYFAdgM4DcO+R6ALJ9mYBDALY1WAByF0aBACrjgAIQDmBAN44AkGgIBBCRNUbtO9ADYivAgFkhYZgAoAlCexaPANyEAnAhDBWYAIAXgJmGgB3AgAZQOAAHgdgAD4NAnQoAlQsgGYCAF8BDzMATkcAIgAPVArnYq9fAhrQ8Kj0gElgGhFWVoCgkgBxGmAAUWYAVzEfIWAKHxdChq1kgjBWvBXIgAtIWUcaki6e1hIbCk8aADkaKuAXZ1MtTXcS4nKjk97ySZ8fGjMYD1Z6rABmBEcYHg8AIaVyrgARgChABrFYFUyY9zY7FAA

Comment: @PavelMayorov сходу на 100% не разберусь, но никакого копирования структуры я там не вижу. Аналогично https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQA7AhgLYCmAzgA74DGxABACpnABCdA3jgJBq0CC55VrQ7ZOnUsABOAVyrA+EmXOFcxyAMy0wueQEkA3Ku6bkAFloBZAPYA3YgDliAD2AAKAJTDau+PH20AX1UA2lUeXh4RMWNaSWJ8GCtcCABPBSlZPWBiQkNRNU1eRUzvbMJ0POiNPjRXIozlME82UpzaAF4tfyD8kLD0ADZaM0t8bQ8VfM4bfElaJ3QO2lxiAHca1FcV9fqleRbdJc0Q90qxBYA6XTKL6ztHFw8z7nQATldL65yr06NPsvQV18z2Qbw+gK+5R+z3+OQhwKMoPesKhul+vS4PR6QA, здесь достаётся ссылка на поле структуры и значение по ссылке инкрементируется. Если кто разбирается - поправьте

Comment: Да, и тут "Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x2.Items, x2.Items));", похоже, значение пакуется при передаче в метод ReferenceEquals (о чём, собственно, текст ошибки и говорит), а не копируется при распаковке из x2.Items.

Comment: Путём сравнения в https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQA7AhgLYCmAzgA74DGxABACpnABCdA3jgJBq0CC55VrQ7ZOnUsABOAVyrA+EmXOFcxyAMy0wueQEkA3Ku6bkAFloBZAPYA3YgDliAD2AAKAJTDau+PH20AX1UA2lUeXh4RMWNaSWJ8GCtcCABPBSlZPWBiQkNRNU1eRUzvbMJ0POiNPjRXIozlME82UpzaAF4tfyD8kLD0ADZaM0t8bQ8VfM4bfElaJ3QO2lxiAHca1FcV9fqleRbdJc0Q90qxBYA6XTKL6ztHFw8z7nQATldL65yr06NPsvQt1sDmcbl+U2Qbw+gK+5R+Zx6nB6PSAA== вижу похоже на то (?), что если поле только для чтения, то создаётся его копия. То есть причина всего этого безобразия именно в том, что поля анонимных типов только для чтения.

Comment: @rotabor у анонимного типа не поля, а **свойства**., если вы приглядитесь по-лучше в том же sharplab - увидите метод get_Items и его вызов. При обращении к свойству структура всегда копируется, независимо от того только для чтения или для чтения-записи оно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, так и есть, потому что геттер свойства копирует значение из внутреннего поля объекта. Но в этом ответе упоминается именно поле. Но для поля про "только для чтения" верно. Уточню свой ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно просто пройтись по списку, то это делается так:

```
var x3 = list.GetEnumerator();
while (x3.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x3.Current);
}
```

И всё работает, как надо. Заставить работать исходный код тоже можно, достаточно получить копию структуры в локальную переменную:

```
var x2 = new { Items = list.GetEnumerator() };
var x4 = x2.Items;
while (x4.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x4.Current);
}
```

Попробует разобраться, что вы запрограммировали. В первом случае "x1.Items" имеет тип "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<int>", что является *ссылочным типом*, во втором "x2.Items" имеет тип "System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Enumerator", что представляет собой структуру (*значащий тип*).

Единственными членами [анонимого типа](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) могут быть только свойства, а получение свойства подразумевает копирование его значения из внутреннего поля объекта. Именно поэтому свойство выдаёт копию структуры, и метод MoveNext() применяется к копии, а не к оригинальной структуре. Можно вместо свойства ипользовать поле, тогда всё будет работать, но если поле "только для чтения", то тоже будет происходить копирование. Иллюстрируется это следующим примером:

```
using System;
namespace TestBh {
    class AppBh {
        struct Astruct {
            int i;
            public void MoveNext() { i++; }
            public int Current { get { return i; } }
        } 
        class Aclass {
            Astruct item;
            public Astruct Item1 { get { return item; } }
            public Astruct Item2;
            public readonly Astruct Item3;
        } 
        static void Main() {
            var x1 = new Aclass();
            x1.Item1.MoveNext(); // Using property
            Console.WriteLine(x1.Item1.Current); // 0
            x1.Item2.MoveNext(); // Using field
            Console.WriteLine(x1.Item2.Current); // 1
            x1.Item3.MoveNext(); //Using read-only field
            Console.WriteLine(x1.Item3.Current); // 0
        }
    }
}
```

Вторым решение может быть такое:

```
class Aclass { public List<int>.Enumerator Items; }
...
var x2 = new Aclass() { Items = list.GetEnumerator() };
while (x2.Items.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x2.Items.Current);
}
```